How to "group by" over a range. Range values are defined in range table
Please someone help me with the following request.
I have list of data
SELECT * FROM DUMMY_DATA;

id    value
------------
1     10
1     11
2     100
3     5
3     9
...
1000  1
1000  20

I need to group IDs into several ranged groups and calculate sum of IDs values for a range.
For instance
IDs_range                   sum_of_values
-----------------------------------------
0-10   (up to 10)         xxxx
11-20  (up to 20)         yyyy
...
1001 - 2000 (up to 2000)  zzz

If I had not many ranges I would use CASE expression as described in the topic Oracle: how to "group by" over a range?
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN age <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
         WHEN age <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
         ELSE '21+' 
       END AS age, 
       COUNT(*) AS n
FROM age
GROUP BY CASE 
           WHEN age <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
           WHEN age <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
           ELSE '21+' 
         END

But I have a hundred of ranges and using CASE expression in this case is not so usable.
I know how to build a range table
WITH IDS_RANGES AS (
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS ID_RANGE FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(10,20,....,1000,2000)
)
SELECT ...

but I can't figure out how to QUERY from both a range table(IDS_RANGES) and DUMMY_DATA table to build the desirable result.

You can use the LAG analytic function to find the minimum bound for the range and then JOIN the two tables:
WITH id_ranges (min_value, max_value) AS (
  SELECT LAG(COLUMN_VALUE, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE) + 1,
         COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(10,20,1000,2000))
)
SELECT r.min_value || '-' || r.max_value AS id_range,
       SUM(value) AS sum_of_values
FROM   dummy_data d
       INNER JOIN id_ranges r
       ON     d.id BETWEEN r.min_value AND r.max_value
GROUP BY r.min_value, r.max_value

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_DATA (id, value) AS
  SELECT    1,  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT    1,  11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT    2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT    3,   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT    3,   9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000,   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000,  20 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID_RANGE
SUM_OF_VALUES




21-1000
21


1-10
135



fiddle
